# ASP.NET MVC WebAPI in Application Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am trying to use WebAPI as part of an MVC5 application. The application has areas, so to keep with the existing structure I have created and "API" area. However, I am having some routing troubles as I get a 404 when hitting the API URL.

I have read a number of posts on this, mostly MVC4 examples and so far I have not had any success.

Initially, I had the API routes as part of the area routing, so above the below default route, I had another with the RouteTemplate `API/{controller}`

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
     context.MapRoute(
          "API_default",
          "API/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
}
```

I then realised my error and moved the API route to a different method in the same area registration file

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "Direct_API",
         routeTemplate: "API/{controller}"
     );
}
```

I have now moved the API routes out of the area registration file completely, created a new API route config file in `app_start` and registered it in `global.asax` before the application routes file. However, still, if I goto `http://localhost:port/API/Import` I do not hit the API Controller.

The API Import Controller sits in the API area of the application

```
public class ImportController : ApiController
{
   [HttpGet]
   public Array Get()
   {
        return new[]{true, false, false, true};
   }
}
```

Global.asax registration

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

I have also tried registering the file MVC4 way which was `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to this but think I will leave the question up to help others in the future. Many of the examples and articles covering this subject and very specific that the `RouteConfig` **must** be after the WebAPI config. I was very careful about this.

However, I completely overlooked that area registrations were running first.
Moving `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` to after `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` solved the issue.

This still leaves the API registration global, which doesn't feel right as its localised to an area. I think i can solve that with attribute routing and the removal of the Area Registration File for the API.